# What is the easiest way to include bootstrap in Craft?

Tags: bootstrap-craft

How is the easiest way to include bootstrap to Craft? I've seen there's already a `bootstrap.php` in the "app" folder... what can I do with this guy?

Comment: I assume you're referring to this [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).  Craft's `craft/app/bootstrap.php` file (while sharing the same name) has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

There are other ways, but since you've asked for the easiest, that's how I'd do it...

Just add it to `/templates/_layout.twig` and extend it to other templates: like `/templates/index.twig` starts with `{% extends "_layout" %}`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// don't forget jquery/popper here
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

PS. Make sure `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` are placed in `/web/css` and `/web/js`
```

Answer (score 1):

Leowebguy pretty much nailed it. I made a scaffold for setting up craft with Foundation 6 if you want to peek through it. Its the same idea, but I've done all the set up for your gulpfile and such if you want to use SASS or any preprocessing. It's a bit different that Bootstrap, as they use grunt by default if I'm not mistaken, but figured I would throw in my two cents.

https://github.com/prkirby/craft-foundation-scaffold

Answer (score 1):

I do things mostly the same way leowebguy does. I'd just add a comment on his, but I don't have enough points yet.

I've got a _layout/base.html file which has some basic structure, and it calls  header & footer files.

But intead of calling my scripts this way:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">`

I do it with the twig include function, like so:

```
{% includeCssFile "/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}

{% includeJsFile "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" %}
{% includeJsFile "/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}
```